# Is there a better way to determine translation distances less than x amount between two entities and then assign an int value thereafter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi to whoever takes their time to read this, and thank you in advance if you have an answer:) I appreciate it.

When one of the players(10 player game) distance is in range with an object entity, I need to assign the players custom int(I've set from 1-10) to the object(I've set all to 0), so when a player collides with an object, it gets the players custom int assigned.

I get the following error at execution when the game starts:

InvalidOperationException: RecruitJob.playerData.Positions is not a value type. Job structs may not contain any reference types.
Unity.Jobs.LowLevel.Unsafe.JobsUtility.CreateJobReflectionData (System.Type type, Unity.Jobs.LowLevel.Unsafe.JobType jobType, System.Object managedJobFunction0, System.Object managedJobFunction1, System.Object managedJobFunction2

```
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Jobs;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using Unity.Burst;
using Unity.Transforms;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[UpdateAfter(typeof(PlayerTransformUpdateSystem))]
class HumanRecruitionSystem : JobComponentSystem
{
    private PlayerPositionData playerData;
    private HumanPositionData humanData;

    protected override JobHandle OnUpdate(JobHandle inputDeps)
    {
        var job = new RecruitJob
        {
            playerData = playerData,
            humanData = humanData,
            recruitionDistance = Settings.PlayerCollisionRadius * Settings.HumanCollisionRadius
        };

        return job.Schedule(playerData.Length, humanData.Length, inputDeps);
    }
}

[BurstCompile]
struct RecruitJob : IJobParallelFor
{
    public PlayerPositionData playerData;

    [NativeDisableParallelForRestriction]
    public HumanPositionData humanData;

    public float recruitionDistance;

    public void Execute(int index)
    {
        var player = playerData.Recruits.Value;
        var human = humanData.Recruits.Value;

        float3 humanPosition = humanData.Positions.transform.position;
        float3 recruitPosition = playerData.Positions.transform.position;

        float distSquared = math.distance(recruitPosition, humanPosition);

        if (distSquared < recruitionDistance)
        {
            human.Value = player.Value;
        }
    }
}

public struct HumanPositionData
{
    public int Length;
    [ReadOnly] public ComponentDataFromEntity<Human> Humans;
    [ReadOnly] public ComponentDataProxy<Translation> Positions;
    public ComponentDataProxy<RecruitedBy> Recruits;
}

public struct PlayerPositionData
{
    public int Length;
    [ReadOnly] public ComponentDataFromEntity<Player> Players;
    [ReadOnly] public ComponentDataProxy<Translation> Positions;
    [ReadOnly] public ComponentDataProxy<RecruitedBy> Recruits;
}
```

Do I need to try a different approach or is there a way to get the translation data through a value type?

Thanks:)

Comment: What is the declaration of Translation? Is it a class? if so, can you make it a struct? It seems to be what the compiler is asking for. Though I would think the compiler would complain earlier that this is not valid type.

Comment: It's a struct( struct Unity.Transforms.Translation) from the new DOTS packages

Comment: Actually, ComponentDataProxy is a class type and would make sense with the error. Maybe you could use a different type of collection. I have never used DOTS.

Comment: it's talking about `RecruitJob.playerData.Positions` is that a class or a struct?

Comment: That's correct, ComponentDataProxy is a class type used to define the translation struct: [ReadOnly] public ComponentDataProxy<Translation> Positions;